# Most suitable payment gateway API for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Please which payment api/toolkit is most suitable for Google app-engine platform. I found Google check-out SDK which seemed really nice but its not available for use in my country (US and UK only). I also found PayPal X toolkit which is very cool but it supports just PayPal card transactions. Are there any more suitable ones that can be widely used?

Comment: This is a business issue not a coding issue.

Comment: This is not really a business issue.  He is wondering which SDKs play nice with GAE.  Let me know what you find. I'm looking for an API to do the same thing, and am not looking to use PayPal.  (I was looking at Chargify, but haven't dug into the API yet.

Comment: Why is this closed. This is one of the biggest issue I am facing right now. What is the payment gateway API that plays well with GAE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [stripe](https://stripe.com/) on my app engine app. I was impressed by how easy it was to implement and its array of features.